# Error when inserting Documents with for Loop

Tags: mongodb, robo3t

When I try to add some Documents to a Collection, exactly 1 of 4 times I get an Error.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 50; i=i+1){
    db.SampleOrder.insert(
    {
        "SampleId": NumberInt(i),
        "PuckId": NumberInt(i)
    });  
}
```

Error:
[Picture of the Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BFrh.png)

Does anybody know why this doesn't work?
I use Robomongo Robo 3T 1.1.1.

Comment: Might want to report it to Robomongo. And add details of the tool version used by you specifically.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `insertMany` instead of `insert` to insert multiple document

like:

```
var docs = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 50; i=i+1){
    docs.push({
        "SampleId": NumberInt(i),
        "PuckId": NumberInt(i)
        });
}
db.SampleOrder.insertMany(docs);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. But my loop isn't finsh like this. It's some kind of a Bug from MongoDB / Robomongo. When I know what exactly triggers the Bug I will post It.

Fact when I've opened a new shell the error was gone with the same loop. And a little later the Error was there again but I think it's a combination from things.